# error for converting mssql to mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I was create a procedure for counting a question set using mssql. I post that query below. Now i want to convert the below query to mysql  but it returns error.Please help me to fix this error..

My partial query is here...

```
     select trainPrecent1 = (select distinct(fldprecentage) from precentage  where    fldgroup='Training' and fldset='First'),
     trainPrecent2 = (select distinct(fldprecentage) from precentage where fldgroup='Training' and fldset='Second'),
     agentPrecent1 = (select distinct(fldprecentage) from precentage where fldgroup='Agent on floor' and fldset='First'),
     agentPrecent2 = (select distinct(fldprecentage) from precentage where fldgroup='Agent on floor' and fldset='Second'), 
     superPrecent1 = (select distinct(fldprecentage) from precentage where fldgroup='Supervisor on floor' and fldset='First'), 
     superPrecent2 = (select distinct(fldprecentage) from precentage where fldgroup='Supervisor on floor' and fldset='Second')
```

Now am getting the following error...

```
 "unknown column name "trainPrecent1" in fielelist...
```

Please help me to fix this error....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TRy using **AS** in place of **=**:

```
select (select distinct(fldprecentage) from precentage  where    
fldgroup='Training' and fldset='First') AS trainPrecent1,
......
```